# Problem with HashSet Serialization / Cloning

Tags: java, serialization, cloning

Why is this failing? I am comparing the serialized form of an empty `HashSet` with the serialized form of its clone created by serialization+deserialization.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

...

final HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
assertThat(SerializationUtils.serialize(hashSet))
    .containsExactly(SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.clone(hashSet)));
```

AssertionError will be thrown.

Something must be not correctly serialized/deserialized in a HashSet. Do you have any idea, what exactly? I am Using OpenJDK 8.

Comment: just FYI: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: @Lino thanks. Yep. But it is not relevant for the question. I add a type for it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something with loadingFactor. If the Hashset is instantiated like this, then it works:

```
new HashSet(0,0.75f);
```

Comment: You better add this to your original post instead of adding a new answer.

Comment: @DorianGray It's OK to have self-answered questions, https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: It doesn't look like an answer. It doesn't explain the problem in the first post.